# Executing a rails .js.erb file from a jquery mobile form

Tags: ruby-on-rails, jquery-mobile

My form spans several jquery mobile pages all within one file and wrapped by this form

new.html.erb

```
<%= form_tag submit_path, :method => :post, :remote => true do%>
```

create.js.erb

```
alert("Hello");
<% debugger %>
$.mobile.changePage("#confirm");
```

The create.js.erb gets hit as my console stops on the debugger, but the alert never fires and neither does the jquery mobile command.

My url goes from `/new#confirm` to just `/new`

I can do the (seemingly) exact same thing in a normal rails form and I get the alert.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently you need to do this completely with Ajax to get rails to respond properly and have the js.erb execute:

In your form add

```
"data-ajax" => "false"
```

then

```
$('#submit_button').click(function(){
  handleSubmit();
  return false
});

function handleSubmit() {
  $.ajax({
    url: "/post_url",
    type: 'POST',
    cache: false,
    beforeSend: function(xhr) {xhr.setRequestHeader('X-CSRF-Token', $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')); $.mobile.showPageLoadingMsg("a", "Submitting"); }, 
    data: $("#the_form").serialize(), 
    success: function(data){
      handleResponse(data):
    }
  });
}
```